# Axios and response data set split to multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios, response

I'm trying to get data from an API using axios command like

```
function fetchData(apiURL){
    let data = [];
    let options = {
        method: "GET",
        url: apiURL,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        credentials: "include"
    };

    axios(options)
        .then(response => {
            data = response.data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("System error : " + error);
        });

    return data;
}
```

but that will produce sets of arrays which will store arrays of JSONs from `response.data` in count of 100 per array set.

I haven't had problem using `fetch()` to retrieve all data. How I can get similar response of one large array of JSON objects instead of a split?

PS.
I have triggered that function in the

```
 componentDidMount() {
        const apiURL = process.env.REACT_APP_API;
        let tableData = fetchData(apiURL);
        console.log("DATA " + JSON.stringify(tableData));
        this.setState({tblData : tableData});
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios requests are asynchronous and return promises, so you need to adjust your example a bit so that your function returns a promise.

```
/**
 * @return {Promise<T>}
 */
function fetchData(apiURL){
    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        url: apiURL,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        credentials: "include"
    };

    return axios(options)
        .then(response => {
            return response.data;
        })
 }
```

Now, when you consume this API do so asynchronously.

```
function somethingThatUpdatesThatUI() {
    fetchData("/api/foo/bar")
       .then((data) => {
           //perform updates to UI or state here
       })
       .catch((err) => {
           //alert the users that an error has happened here
       })
}
```

Comment: Looks promising but I need to get it triggered from React `componentDidMount()`. Before I was calling `fetchData` there. I have update OP with that

Answer (score 1):

You can update the componentDidMount function:

```
componentDidMount() { 
  const apiURL = process.env.REACT_APP_API; 
  fetchData(apiURL).then(data => { 
    console.log(data ${JSON.stringify(tableData)}) 
    this.setState({tblData : data});
  }) 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I have done based on Robert's answer. On another hand is it better to do that from `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount`? I'm trying to minimize as much as possible displaying empty table before retrieving the data.